# getting counterintuitive results with numpy FFT when calculating mean frequency and ESD Progression

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have some timecourse data that visually appears to have differing levels of high frequency fluctuation.  I have plotted the timecourse Data A and B below.

I have used numpy FFT to perform Fourier Transformation as follows:

```
Fs = 1.0;  # sampling rate
Ts = 864000; # sampling interval
t = np.arange(0,Ts,Fs) # time vector
n = 864000 # number of datapoints of timecourse data
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
frq = frq[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

Y = np.fft.fft(A1)/n # fft computing and normalization of timecourse data (A1)
Y = Y[range(n/2)]
Z = abs(Y)

#####  Calculate Mean Frequency ########

Mean_Frequency = sum((frq*Z))/(sum(Z))

################################make sure the first value doesnt create an issue
Freq = frq[1:]
Z = Z[1:]
max_y = max(Z)  # Find the maximum y value
mode_Frequency = Freq[Z.argmax()]  # Find the x value corresponding to the maximum y value


###################### Plot figures
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig.suptitle(str(D[k]), fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

ax[0].plot(t,A1, 'black')
ax[0].set_xlabel('Time')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax[1].plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
ax[1].set_xscale('log')

ax[1].set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('|Y(freq)|')
text(2*mode_x, 0.95*max_y, "Mode Frequency (Hz): "+str(mode_x))
text(2*mode_x, 0.85*max_y, "Mean Frequency (Hz): "+str(mean_x))
```

plt.savefig("/home/phoenix/Desktop/Figures/Figure3/FourierGraphs/"+str(D[k])+".png")
    plt.close()

This results look like this:

[image]

The timecourse data (black) for A on the left appears to me to have much more high frequency noise than than the data on the right (B).

yet the mean frequency is higher for the data on the left.

Is this because I have performed FFT incorrectly, or because I have  calculated mean frequency incorrectly or because I need to use a different method to capture the really low frequency noise in timecourse B?

thanks for your time.

Comment: What doe mean by "mean frequency"?

Comment: mean as in average